# Why we dont have to check if the number is prime when getting prime factors?

Tags: java, math, primes, prime-factoring

This is a typical code to find prime factors:

```
public static List<Integer> primeFactors(int numbers) {
    int n = numbers;
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
      while (n % i == 0) {
        factors.add(i);
        n /= i;
      }
    }
    if (n > 1) {
      factors.add(n);
    }
    return factors;
  }
```

My question is why don't we check if i is prime or not before adding it to the list?

Comment: Because any number that's added is prime, this is ensured by the for and while loop.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do a proof by contradiction to show that that can't happen.

Imagine that some composite number gets added to the list. There must be some *smallest* composite number that's added to the list. Let's call it c, and imagine that its smallest prime factor is p. We know that p < c, so the loop must have run with p before it ran with c. When the loop did run with p, we know that the loop would find p as a divisor of the number n, because p is a divisor of c and c is a divisor of n. But after doing this, the code would have updated n by dividing out all copies of p. That means that when we got to the part where the loop ran on the number c, the number c wouldn't divide n any more because p divides c, but p does not divide this new value of n (remember, we divided out all copies of p). Therefore, c wouldn't have been added to the list - a contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

here we don't need to check weather the number is prime or not because
the number is going to add is definitely prime.. lets take some example

1)16  its a multiple of 2,4,8,16 but only 2 is added because of while loop

2)18  its multiple is 2,3,6,9 and 18 but only 2 and 3 ,3 is added because of while loop

3) n an integer
we don't know its multiple but
when i=2 the number is become odd so now all the even number get eliminate (means any number multiple of two is not divisible by n/2 )

when i=3 if mod is zero then add and all the multiple of three get eliminate 
(means any number multiple of 3 is not divisible by n/3)

and this is how we calculate that the number is prime or not i.e. like by taking dividing a number by 2 then it also not ab multiple of  4,6,8 etc

In sort we are eliminating the other number except the by dividing it with small numbers

i hope you understand the logic